# Latex math encapsulating complex expression in bracket

Tags: brackets, amsmath

Latex newbie here. I've clumsily built the following math expression in Latex

[image]

```
\begin{align}
&W_{i'}(\alpha) = \cdots \notag\\
&\vdots \notag\\
           &W_i(\alpha) = \sum\limits_\zeta \underline{q_\zeta} \cdot \underline{\Omega(\alpha, \zeta, \hat{u}_{i}^k, \xi )} \\
           &\qquad \qquad \quad \ \ \downarrow \qquad \qquad \uparrow \notag\\
           &\qquad \qquad \quad \ \ \beta_i^k (\zeta) \rightarrow \hat{u}_i^k(\mathbf{x}, t) \\
&\vdots \notag\\
&W_{i''}(\alpha) = \cdots \notag
\end{align}
```

and would now like to append a `f(n) = \left{` to the left of it.

How do I do this without rewriting the entire code in terms of an array? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Afterwards you will have only one equation, therefore I assume that the two tags are now longer necessary. If this is the case proceed as follows:

1. Remove all `\notags`
2. change `align` to `aligned`
3. Enclose everything with rest of equation.

Here the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    f(n) = \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        &W_{i'}(\alpha) = \cdots \\
        &\vdots \\
        &W_i(\alpha) = \sum\limits_\zeta \underline{q_\zeta} \cdot \underline{\Omega(\alpha, \zeta, \hat{u}_{i}^k, \xi )} \\
        &\qquad \qquad \quad \ \ \downarrow \qquad \qquad \uparrow \\
        &\qquad \qquad \quad \ \ \beta_i^k (\zeta) \rightarrow \hat{u}_i^k(\mathbf{x}, t) \\
        &\vdots \\
        &W_{i''}(\alpha) = \cdots 
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```